# How to supress with ragged2e in a glossary (longtable)?

Tags: longtable, glossaries, ragged2e

I am trying to use the `long` style provided in the `glossary` package to use in my  acronym list. However, I am also using the `ragged2e` package and I have my paragraphs indented too. This causes both the table and the first line of the acronym description to be indented. Any suggestions?

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[top=1.0in,hmargin=1.25in,height=9.0in,letterpaper,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[acronyms,nonumberlist,nopostdot,nogroupskip]{glossaries}

\setlength{\RaggedRightParindent}{0.5in}

\setacronymstyle{long-short}
\renewcommand*{\glsnamefont}[1]{\normalfont{#1}}
\newacronym{AAA}{AAA}{some text}
\newacronym{BBB}{BBB}{some very very very very very very very very very very very very very long long long long long long long long text}
\newacronym{CCC}{CCC}{an acronym}

\makenoidxglossaries
\setglossarystyle{long}
\newlength\glsnamewidth
\settowidth{\glsnamewidth}{MMMMM}
\setlength{\glsdescwidth}{\textwidth-\glsnamewidth-\tabcolsep}
\renewenvironment{theglossary}%
{\begin{longtable}[l]{@{}p{\glsnamewidth}p{\glsdescwidth}}}%
{\end{longtable}}%

\begin{document}
\doublespace
\printnoidxglossary[type=acronym,title={LIST OF ACRONYMS}]
\printacronyms

\gls{AAA}. Text text text \gls{BBB}. More text \gls{CCC}.

\end{document}
```

Gives:

[image: Wrong]

While I want it to look more like the next one, albeit with the following text indented.

[image: Right]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a way by changing the indentation inside the renewed `glossary` environment and then resetting it after the closing of the table. It works for this case, but unsure if there is a more elegant way.

Full code:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[top=1.0in,hmargin=1.25in,height=9.0in,letterpaper,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[acronyms,nonumberlist,nopostdot,nogroupskip]{glossaries}

\setlength{\RaggedRightParindent}{0.5in}

\setacronymstyle{long-short}
\renewcommand*{\glsnamefont}[1]{\normalfont{#1}}
\newacronym{AAA}{AAA}{some text}
\newacronym{BBB}{BBB}{some very very very very very very very very very very very very very long long long long long long long long text}
\newacronym{CCC}{CCC}{an acronym}

\makenoidxglossaries
\setglossarystyle{long}
\newlength\glsnamewidth
\settowidth{\glsnamewidth}{MMMMM}
 \setlength{\glsdescwidth}{\textwidth-\glsnamewidth-\tabcolsep}
\renewenvironment{theglossary}{%
    \setlength{\RaggedRightParindent}{0pt}\begin{longtable}[l{@{}p{\glsnamewidth}p{\glsdescwidth}}}%
{\end{longtable}\setlength{\RaggedRightParindent}{0.5in}}%

\begin{document}
\doublespace
\printnoidxglossary[type=acronym,title={LIST OF ACRONYMS}]
\printacronyms

\gls{AAA}. Text text text \gls{BBB}. More text \gls{CCC}.

\end{document}
```